# Reactive Extensions installation package doesn't contain ReactiveUI libraries

Tags: c#, system.reactive, reactiveui

I want to try ReactiveUI however Rx installation package doesn't contain ReactiveUI. I guess that ReactiveUI is in some standalone installation package, but I was not able to find it. Can anybody share with information whether or not ReactiveUI is supported by Microsoft anymore? And if yes please give me a link to ReactiveUI library.

Thank you in advance!

UPD: I've found a sample application on http://www.reactiveui.net/. It contains ReactiveUI dlls, but I want to get official ReactiveUI build.

Comment: What exactly do you expect in an 'official build' in addition to the class libraries?

Comment: I'm looking for ReactiveUI.dll & ReactiveUI.Xaml.dll

Comment: ReactiveUI is not a Microsoft library. It is a third-party library.

Comment: Now it become undestanable why Rx installation package doesn't contain RxUI

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ReactiveUI is not a Microsoft project - the best way to get official binaries for ReactiveUI is via the NuGet package, which will also pull in the correct version of the Reactive Extensions.

Answer (score 2):

If you go to the website you mention http://www.reactiveui.net/, there is a 'download' button at the bottom. This gives you both a sample application *and* the ReactiveUI libraries.

You can find the dlls you mention under `ReactiveUI 2.2.0.0 Sample\ReactiveUI.Sample\ReactiveUI.Sample\bin\Debug\`

Or, of course, grab the source from their [github](http://github.com/xpaulbettsx/ReactiveUI) and compile them yourself.

P.S. I found all of that with no prior knowledge of this library. Maybe this was more of a quesion for Google, not this site?

Comment: It's not exactly that I'm looking for. These libraries are included to sample, however I'm looking for official build.

Comment: What makes them not an official build? They have correct version numbers and other metadata. Looks like an official build to me.

Comment: Yes, but I'm not sure if Microsoft releases new build it will be updated in this sample

Comment: Microsoft? While Rx is a Microsoft research project, I'm not sure they maintain ReactiveUI; it looks to be third party. Either way, if you're desperate for the latest source then just compile it yourself!

Comment: @AlexanderR It is third-party - Paul Betts made it.  Rx itself is no longer a research project hosted in DevLabs - it's had a full official release, and v2.0 is in beta now.

Comment: Don't look at the current sample for current best-practices, it's hella old. I'm working on a new one for RxUI 3.0